# Why a number like 01 gives a Syntax error in python interactive mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

Why a number like `01` gives a *Syntax error* when `01` is typed in python interactive mode and pressed enter?

When `00` is entered the interpreter evaluates to `0`, however numbers like `01`, `001` or anything which starts with a `0` is entered *Syntax error:invalid token* is displayed.

Entering `1,000` in prompt evaluates to a tuple of `(1,0)` but `1,001` doesn't evaluate to `(1,1)` instead *Syntax error* is displayed.

Why does the Python interpreter behave so?

Comment: It doesnt produce a syntax error when doing 01. The interpreter gives 1.

Comment: @limelights It depends on the version of Python. `2.7` gives 1, `3.2` gives a syntax error for me.

Comment: @Yuushi Ah, I'm not well versed in Python 3 yet. I had no idea that they scrapped octal literals.

Comment: @limelights Neither did I to be honest.

Comment: It is only the leading zero syntax for octal literals that has gone - not octal literals in general. The alternate prefix `0o` (along with `0b` for binary, and, since longer ago, `0x` for hex) is available from late in the 2.x series (I think 2.6, but maybe not till 2.7).

Answer (score 11):

Historically, integer literals starting with zero denoted octal numbers. This [has been abolished in Python 3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/#removal-of-old-octal-syntax), and replaced with a different syntax (`0o...`).

The old syntax is no longer accepted, [except when the number consists entirely of zeros](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals):

```
Python 3.3.0 (default, Dec  1 2012, 19:05:43) 
>>> 0
0
>>> 00
0
>>> 01
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    01
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: +1, and a link to the doc for an explanation: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/#removal-of-old-octal-syntax

Comment: Do you know why it exists when the number consists entirely of zeros?

Comment: @jamylak: I am guessing due to lack of ambiguity (there's no uncertainty about the number denoted by `000000`). Although it's hard to see how that would make any practical difference.

Comment: @NPE Maybe it's so people can have fun by holding down the `0` key on IDLE. Actually I realized why now, it has lots of real world applications such as digital time

Comment: The non-ambiguity argument holds for 01 in the same way as for 00 for all number bases and for upto 07 for previously octal numbers, but this is more a problem of python itself.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x, a leading zero in an integer literal means it is interpreted as octal. This was dropped for Python 3, which requires the `0o` prefix. A leading zero in a literal was left as a syntax error so that old code relying on the old behavior breaks loudly instead of silently giving the "wrong" answer.

Comment: Do you have idea why the feature might removed?...in most of language 0 prefixed number is Octal..

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: The rationale is explained in the PEP: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/#removal-of-old-octal-syntax